# Required time for Orly with fast track

Tags: airports, ory

I will be departing from Paris Orly at weekday 6 PM. I heard it can be quite crowded and a security queue can last very long time. How much time shall I reserve? I bought a fast track option with Transavia.

Comment: Orly security can be a mess. Sometimes the “random inspection ratio” seems to be set to 1/3, and then it backs up a lot. Also pay attention to the place where you enter fast track (big “Accès N°1” arch), they sometimes act like it’s just closed off, you need to actively ask to go through. On quiet days with fast track just security can take a good 15 minutes. Also if you have to go through exit passport control you need to factor that in, especially if you can’t use the e-gates. No experience with flights at that time though, that’s why I’m just commenting.

Comment: Without fast-track at 5am, I had security take a good 20min

Comment: Thanks. I am travelling within Schengen area, so I guess that I don't need exit control. We'll walk just with backpacks, online check-in. So I guess that arriving with Orlyval 120 minutes prior departure should be very safe having that fast track and still doable, if denied the fast track for any reason.